# How to truly set the Toggle accent/tint color in SwiftUI. Currently it's darker than what I'm setting it to

Tags: swiftui

Here is an example of what's currently happening. Above I have a rectangle being set to a color, and below I have a toggle with the tint being set to the SAME color, however SwiftUI is rendering it darker than it's being set to. The top example is the system's default Color.accentColor, below is a custom one. The values for the colors you're seeing in order from top to bottom is:

```
  R10 G96 B254
  R21 G90 B208

  R60 G255 B68
  R36 G151 B53
```

If I set the color to `R60 G255 B68`, why does SwiftUI assume that I wanted the color `R36 G151 B53`? Is there anyway to get it to show the color I input?
[image: Demo]

Code:

```
HStack{
    VStack {
        Rectangle().frame(width: 300, height: 20).foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
        Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $toggle).toggleStyle(.switch).tint(Color.accentColor)
    }
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
```

Comment: There's probably some intermediary subview that's tinted black... might be hard to work around

Comment: I can recreate that difference if the accent color has an opacity less than 100. Then the displayed accent color picks up what's underneath. The toggle and rectangle I tested apparently differ. Are you certain the opacity is 100?

Comment: @Marcy Yes. I just tried with a brand new project. Set the accent color to #FF0000 with 100 opacity. I even placed the rectangle and the toggle on a completely white view to rule out opacity against a dark background. And even with all that, my rectangle was R255 G0 B0, and the toggle was R214 G38 B22. I think Apple just changes the color on their end, and that the only way to get the same color is implement your own toggle. When you try on your computer, are you getting the exact same color as you're entering? I'm using Digital Color Meter to check.

Comment: I'm getting the same color. I used Apple's Colors panel and the eyedropper. Visually, my colors look the same though, yours don't. Any accessibility settings?